# Checking if Javascript string is HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection

I have a textbox and submit button which posts the content and a reply to the HTML page.  Is there any way (other than checking if the string's substring at the beginning is

```
    <h1>,<h2>,<h3>...,<script>,<style>,etc.
```

to see if a string will be formatted differently when it is posted on the page, in order to prevent code injection?

Thanks

-Zach

Comment: You shouldnt be doing this check in the browser but on the server where you can ensure the client doens't hack the submit

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you:
 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/942032/772020

Comment: maybe add the string to a detached node and check if its.innerText == its.innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you display user data, you should correctly encode it as html. In javascript, use `document.createTextNode(userData)` and append that node instead of using innerHTML. In PHP, use `htmlentities`.

If the user is allowed to use any html or formatting, you should do them with a strict whitelist of allowed tags and attributes, and encode everything else as plain text.

So, even if the user did enter `<h1>stuff</h1>`, when that's properly encoded, it will come out as `&lt;h1&gt;test&lt;/h1&gt;` instead of html, which won't be vulnerable to javascript injection.