# Prevent user from injecting javascript/markup into element

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I'm attempting to write a chat server and I've come across the issue that if someone puts markup in their messages e.g. `<strong>blah</strong>` then the message will send with bold text. Someone could take it further by putting scripts in their message. I'm not sure how I can avoid this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Javascript injection attacks within user-generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942011/how-to-prevent-javascript-injection-attacks-within-user-generated-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter your input to take out unwanted tags. There really isn"t much else to it.