# How can I filter out all other tags other than b, u and i when trying to render content using .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm gathering text in form using textarea and I plan to render that text using `.innerHTML` so that the user can make the content bold, italic and underlined. I might decide to increase the flexibility to allow coloured text using style attribute as well.

I have considered using regex to match the text but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.

### This is what I currently have

```html
      <div class="fullblog-container">
        <textarea name="title" id="fullblogTitle"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="addBlock" onclick="submitBlocks()">SUBMIT</button>
```

```js
       const fullBlogContainer = document.querySelector(".fullblog-container");
      function submitBlocks() {
        const allChildren = Array.from(fullBlogContainer.children);
        const filterChildren = allChildren.filter((elem) => elem.tagName != "BUTTON");
        console.log(filterChildren[0].value);
      }
```

The above code gets the output from (currently only 1 textarea) all my textareas.

I plan to rendder that value using `.innerHTML` and wish to retain b, u, i tags and maybe div tags with style attributes, and treat the rest as text.

Edit: Although my question results in preventing injection attacks (similar question exists) I require a way to render certain parts as text and other parts as html, and I haven't found a suitable solution for this.

PS: NO JQuery please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Javascript injection attacks within user-generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942011/how-to-prevent-javascript-injection-attacks-within-user-generated-html)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I require a way to render specific parts as text and and the rest as html, so I don't believe that answers my question.

Comment: @jabaa How would I do that for div tags with style attributes? ... for the future.

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting downvotes, I have done my research and not found any suitable method to accomplish this task. I haven't seen any similar StackOverflow question either.

Comment: Please may you show us the input, the current output of your own code, and the desired output? Make sure it is a [mcve]

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have added some more code, regarding what I'm trying to do. The result I wish to obtain is to be able to treat certain tags as text, I can't show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to convert all elements to text and whitelist elements you want to allow. With `innerText` the browser converts all html entities to their code. Then you can read actual code with `innerHTML` and replace whitelisted elements.

```js
const dangerousContent = '\<script\>dangerousFunction()\</script\>';
const content = 'Text \<b\>bold\</b\> \<i\>italic\</i\>  \<u\>underline\</u\>';

const container = document.getElementById('container');

container.innerText += dangerousContent;
container.innerText += content;
container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML
                               .replace(/&lt;b&gt;/g, '\<b\>')
                               .replace(/&lt;\/b&gt;/g, '\</b\>')
                               .replace(/&lt;i&gt;/g, '\<i\>')
                               .replace(/&lt;\/i&gt;/g, '\</i\>')
                               .replace(/&lt;u&gt;/g, '\<u\>')
                               .replace(/&lt;\/u&gt;/g, '\</u\>');
```

```html
<span id="container"></span>
```

Comment: How would I allow div tags with style attributes? I apologize I've never used regex before.

Comment: @rishi I will think about the divs but that's not that simple. First you have to find the divs containing only styles. That can be done with a regex. Then you have to find the corresponding closing tag. AFAIK that's not possible with a regex.

Comment: Ah ok, so maybe a possible solution could be to look for something like `<red>` and replace that with `<span style="color: red">` ? Would that be an appropriate solution? ... it would make things easier for the user also.

Comment: @rishi Yes, that could be implemented the same way the other tags are replaced. But keep in mind that a span, div and all other tags can contain malicious code: https://jsfiddle.net/2ms4jyax/4/ Sanitize the content.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I'll accept this answer in a while. This is a great answer but I was initially hoping for something without regex (but maybe I was hoping for too much :) ).